# What is the solution to $a^*_i = arg min_{a_i} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(b_i - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i a_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}\right)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, optimization

Let $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ denote a vector, where $b = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & \ldots & b_n \end{bmatrix}^T$, and let $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ denote a vector where $a = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \ldots & a_n \end{bmatrix}^T$

I'm trying to find $a^* \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, where
$$a^*_i = \operatorname{arg}\operatorname{min}_{a_i} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(b_i - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i a_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}\right)^2$$

My thought is that it might be easier to work with the above in matrix form. Let $B$ denote a diagonal matrix with $b$ on the diagonal, then we have

$$a^* = \operatorname{arg}\operatorname{min}_{a} ||b - (a^Ta)^{-1} a^T B a||^2_2$$

I know the above is minimized when
$$\bar{b} = (a^Ta)^{-1} a^T B a$$

My question is, is there a way to isolate $a$ from here?

Comment: Have you tried to find a solution where you only use the $a_i$ corresponding to the smallest and largest element of $b$, setting the other $a_i$ to $0$?

Comment: It is $\frac{b_1 + \cdots + b_n}{n} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i a_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\bar{b} = (a^Ta)^{-1} a^T B a = \frac{1}{||a||^2}a^T B a = \frac{1}{||a||}a^T B \frac{1}{||a||}a = u^T . B . u
$ where $||u|| = 1$

From there it is easy to find that $u_i = 1$ if $b_i = \max_j{b_j}$ and $0$ else. You can take $a = u$ as a result